# Clearing a text file without deleting it

Tags: vb.net, file, text

I have a text file to which I will be appending data(hence I can't just overwrite the file). The thing is that originally it does contain content I do not want, so before I start appending new data. Is there a way to clear the file without having to delete and then re-create it?

Comment: Rename it and then re-create it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464261/filestream-and-streamwriter-how-to-truncate-the-remainder-of-the-file-after-wr ?

Comment: Why not just overwrite the file to start with -- with an empty string -- and then append your data afterwards?

Comment: Overwriting it with an empty string sounds good. Is File.WriteAllText the best option?

Comment: Yes, you could use that.

Comment: Opening the file and replacing the contents before adding more text, is just the long way of overwriting.

Comment: @Plutonix -- Not if you want to preserve the original create date and other metadata.

Comment: roryap, could you post a solution so I could accept it - I went with your suggestion:  File.WriteAllText(Path,"")

Comment: What function are you going to write all the new data with?  Both `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText()` and `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines()` will overwrite **and** truncate the file if there was any old data in it.  I don't see why you need to explicitly make it blank beforehand...

Comment: Idle_mind, that's because then I will append to the file inside the loop. So if I use WriteAllText then, it will clear the file every iteration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can start by overwriting the file with an empty string, and then append your data afterwards.  You could use this to overwrite the file:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path, "")
```

The benefit of this as opposed to deleting and recreating the file is that you will preserve the original create date of the file along with any other metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most .NET methods allow you to either append or overwrite. You already found one method that could do it - **File.WriteAllText**. The only drawback is that it's non-streamed, so for a lot of content, you may need a lot of memory. [File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) is a stream version. It may look like more code (and it is), but it can be useful in situations when you simply cannot afford to put all your contents in memory at once. [Example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3h7b61.aspx):

```
Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt" 

' Create or overwrite the file. 
Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)

' Add text to the file. 
Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(
                           "This is some text in the file.")
fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
fs.Close()
```

Comment: so what if it's not streamed?

Comment: @SharenEayrs: Then it's `File.WriteAllText`.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength(v=vs.110).aspx

FileStream.SetLength(0);

Set the FileStream Length to zero. I have included the docs from MSDN.

Comment: Please add a code sample. This is something new for me.