# Is it possible to make StreamWriter overwrite line without closing the .txt?

Tags: c#, streamwriter, overwrite

If StreamWriter has an auto-updating output like some list:

```
Cute cat.
Angry dog.
Huge elephant.
Eternal sunshine.
```

or

```
1
2
3
4
```

How is it possible to force StreamWriter to write this list in **one** line? Dog overwrites cat, elephant overwrites dog, sunshine overwrites elephant and so on. Thus we can see the only one line changing in .txt, **not console**!

All Console.() deviations solve the problem in **console only**, but the .txt file collects new strings on and on.

Comment: No.  Keyword is *stream*.  You will have to rewrite the file.

Comment: Does TextWriter solves the problem?

Comment: Look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288401/c-sharp-filestream-both-lock-a-file-and-at-the-same-time-be-able-to-read-it-w

Comment: You can access the underlying stream via `BaseStream` and set its position to 0 and length (using `SetLength` on `FileStream`).

Comment: @Steve Mitcham unfortunately that does not solve my problem due to answer of Blindy. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You don't give a lot of context.  That being said, there is very little time between between the overwrite and flush for things to go wrong. My answer assumed that this is the only data you have in the file.  If you are intending something more complex, I'd rewrite your question with additional detail.

Comment: @Steve Mitcham I'm trying to pull your example at the moment. Maybe I will figure something out.

Comment: In that case, why don't you write up a new question with a larger view of what you are trying to acheive, that is, why do you want to do this and you will probably get a better way of accomplishing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288401/c-sharp-filestream-both-lock-a-file-and-at-the-same-time-be-able-to-read-it-w) you want to reset the file stream each time you write

```
public void OverwriteFile(Stream writer, string text) 
{
    writer.BaseStream.Seek(0,0);
    writer.BaseStream.SetLength(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text).Length));
    writer.Write(text);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Dispose the stream once you are finished writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically enough, all streams **can** do is overwrite, and that's what makes it impossible to get what you want.

What you actually want is to delete/insert characters, and have the rest of the bytes in the file rearrange themselves, but that's just not how streams work (in particular neither disk based files nor network I/O can suddenly change their length in the middle of the stream).

You have two ways of doing this:

- You write a temporary file entirely with the data you want in the order you want, then delete the old file and rename the temporary to match the old file's name.
- You do it in place. Open the stream as append, read what you need, move the pointer to the beginning, write it all at once then close it (make sure to set the length if you shrunk it). More prone to data corruption if your program isn't able to handle exceptions gracefully. Or you know, power outages. Blue screens. Driver crashes. Cats tapping the RAM connectors with their claws. That sort of thing.